# Html hr tag is not working for outlook when trying to remove line of hr tag

Tags: html, email, web, outlook, automation

I am using `<hr style='border:0'>` for printing line in single line.However the same is working in Chrome and not working for outlook mail only.I want to remove horizontal line from outlook email.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add a single horizontal line:

```
<hr style="border-width: 0; background: #000; color: #000; height:1em">
```

Checkout this guide as well - https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/hr

Comment: Thank you for your response,but i am not looking for to print horizintal line, i am looking for not to  display horizontal line.I am using hr tag to display content in one line without line break.so i use hr tag here